# Asp.net Web API normalize arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Say I have a controller like:

```
public class MyController : ApiController {
    [Route("{myarg}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<Foo> Get(string myarg)
    {
        return await ...
    }
}
```

The `myarg` argument needs to be 'normalized'. Let's say I always want to trim it, uppercase it and string-reverse it. The actual operations don't matter, they're just an example so I'm not looking for methods to trim or reverse a string.

I have a bunch of controllers with all a bunch of methods with all similar arguments. I'd like to have a way to annotate those methods or do something else to make sure the arguments are always 'normalized' before they are even passed into the method. I have looked into route constraints ([custom route constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#custom-route-constraints) in particular) but that doesn't provide a method to do what I want (which makes sense since it's not a real constraint).

Ideally I'd like to annotate the method with an attribute like:

```
[MyNormalize("{myarg}")]
```

Or something in a similar fashion like the `RouteAttribute`s. What would be the best way to go about this and implement this in a clean fashion?

Comment: And when you're going to unit-test that method, what will you pass as `myarg`? Why shouldn't it be part of the method? Ideally, you'll want to tweak model-binding in order to correctly bind the value, not to transform it.

Comment: Regardless of my above comment, you can apply a custom model-binder for this particular parameter and transform it as you wish.

Comment: You can also use an action filter, while @haim770 is writing his answer, I'll do the same :)

Comment: @haim770 The reason I want to do it this way is because we deal a lot with phonenumbers and, internally, they're always stored in E.164 format. However, that means a number is formatted as `+123...` and a `+` in a route like `/foo/bar/+123...` is not a good idea. So we allow for `/foo/bar/123` but then I want to get the 'normalization' out of the way even before we execute the action. Yes, I can do it *in* the action but I don't think it belongs there; we don't do it for other arguments simply because they never contain any invalid characters but a phonenumber is an exception to the rule.

Comment: @RobIII, I understand. Personally, I would still go with a utility/helper that will transform/sanitize the values. What if your transformation logic changes (you want to strip out all leading '0' after '+')? You'll have to unit-test your model-binder instead of a simple utility class. Another option would be to call that utility/helper from within the model-binder...

Comment: @haim770 _'Another option would be to call that utility/helper from within the model-binder... '_ And that's **exactly** what I'm planning to do. We have a "phonenumber normalizer" class and it's been unit-tested to death, inside and outside and also field-proven for about 10 years now with no (more) issues so I'm quite happy to drop it in there and leave it at that (from a unittesting standpoint) since it's unittested on it's own.

Answer (score 5):

It's worth noting that ideally, you'll only want to tweak model-binding in order to correctly *bind* the passed value, not *transforming* it.

Anyway, here's the custom model-binder:

```
public class MyArgModelBinder : System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        // transform to upper-case
        var transformedValue = val.AttemptedValue.ToUpperInvariant();

        bindingContext.Model = transformedValue;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then apply it:

```
[Route("{myarg}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<Foo> Get([ModelBinder(typeof(MyArgModelBinder))] string myarg)
{
    // at this point, `myarg` would contain the transformed value

    ...
}
```

See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#model-binders)

Comment: See [my explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986092/asp-net-web-api-normalize-arguments/51986467#comment90923198_51986092) on the _why_. Now I need to decide if I like your modelbinder better or the action filter. I will accept as soon as I made my decision. Thanks for thinking with me though!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with an [action filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs), intercept the parameters in the `OnActionExecuting` method and change the value in there. For example:

```
public class NormalizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _parameter;

    public NormalizeAttribute(string parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //Get the value passed in
        var value = (string)actionContext.ActionArguments[_parameter];

        //Trim, uppercase, reverse and put the value back in the parameter dictionary
        actionContext.ActionArguments[_parameter] = new string(
            value.Trim().ToUpper().Reverse().ToArray());

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
[Route("{myarg}")]
[HttpGet]
[Normalize("myarg")]
public async Task<Foo> Get(string myarg)
{
    return await ...
}
```

Note that this code needs error checking etc. You would also probably want to make it cope with multiple parameters.

Downside of this method is that there is no strict checking on the parameter name, so they could go out of sync.

Comment: See [my explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986092/asp-net-web-api-normalize-arguments/51986467#comment90923198_51986092) on the _why_. Now I need to decide if I like your action filter better or the modelbinder. I will accept as soon as I made my decision. Thanks for thinking with me though!